# Why is std::make_unique not implemented using list initialization?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, language-design, list-initialization

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique writes that `std::make_unique` can be implemented as

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

This does not work for plain structs with no constructors. Those can be brace-initialized but don't have a non-default constructor. Example:

```
#include <memory>
struct point { int x, z; };
int main() { std::make_unique<point>(1, 2); }
```

[Compiling this](https://ideone.com/FB3fQ7) will have the compiler complain about lack of a 2-argument constructor, and rightly so.

I wonder, is there any technical reason not to define the function in terms of brace initialization instead? As in

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

That [works well enough](https://ideone.com/BDsq1S) for the scenario above. Are there any other legitimate use cases this would break?

Seeing how the general trend appears to prefer braces for initialization, I would assume making braces in that template would be the canonical choice, but the fact that the standard doesn't do it might be an indication of me missing something.

Comment: Consider situation when you call `make_unique<vector<int>>(10,20)` what do you want to get ? vector with 10 items, all 20 value (when () is used in make_unique), or vector with 2 items 10,20 (when {} is used, vector has constructor which takes initializer_list).

Comment: If it's any consolation, there's [p0960](https://wg21.link/p0960) in the pipeline. Future versions of C++ may support aggregates without needing to change the implementation of how factory library functions work.

Comment: Although conceivably, it's possible to support stuff like that today with the help of the `std::is_aggregate` trait. I guess people felt it's better to have a language solution to that, rather than a library one.

Comment: "Seeing how the general trend appears to prefer braces for initialization" I am afraid due to problem with vector etc there is no such trend anymore.

Comment: From [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt), it was done to match `make_shared`. I have yet to find why `make_shared` chose one way over the other. `shared_ptr` was in TR1 though, long before unified initialisation syntax existed - not certain if `make_shared` existed back then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some classes have different behavior with the 2 initialization styles. e.g.

```
std::vector<int> v1(1, 2); // 1 element with value 2
std::vector<int> v2{1, 2}; // 2 elements with value 1 & 2
```

There might not be enough reason to choose one prefer to another; I think the standard just choose one and state the decision explicitly.

As the workaround, you might want to implement your own `make_unique` version. As you have showed, it's not a hard work.

Comment: C++20 changes this answer I believe.

Comment: No, C++20 will not break anything from the answer. The 2 versions of std::vector constructors will still be different and make_shared will still call the round brace constructor (the committee will never support changes that break tons of code). However, C++20 will allow aggregate initialization with standard braces.

Answer (score 28):

In C++20, this will compile:

```
std::make_unique<point>(1, 2);
```

due to the new rule [allowing initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](https://wg21.link/p0960).

---

In C++17, you can just do:

```
std::unique_ptr<point>(new point{1, 2});
```

That won't work with `make_shared` though. So you can also just create a factory (forwarding left as an exercise):

```
template <typename... Args>
struct braced_init {
    braced_init(Args... args) : args(args...) { }
    std::tuple<Args...> args;

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const {
        return std::apply([](Args... args){
            return T{args...};
        }, args);
    }
};

std::make_unique<point>(braced_init(1, 2));
```

In C++14, you'll have to implement `apply` and write a factory function for `braced_init` because there's no CTAD yet - but these are doable.

---

> Seeing how the general trend appears to prefer braces for initialization

Citation needed. It's a charged topic - but I definitely disagree with the claim.

Comment: Parenthesized initialization has its own daemon too. This initializer class would be more complex if it were doing non braced direct initialization.

Comment: With C++20 this still won't compile: `auto p = std::make_unique<std::array<int, 2>>(1, 2);` C++ initialization is a riddle wrapped in a mystery inside an enigma.

Comment: @AmirKirsh we can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) that Parenthesized initialization of aggregate (P0960R3) is only available on gcc >= 10, Clang >= 16 and not available on Apple Clang - reason why I was unable to compile this. –. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74885772/10360134) that gives features tests code to figure out if you have access to this feature on your compiler version.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to other answers, in his [presentation](https://youtu.be/22jIHfvelZk?t=3281) on C++17, **Alisdair Meredith** gives the following implementation of `make_unique`:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> std::unique_ptr<T> {
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value)
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    else
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

It uses C+17 `if constexpr`, but can easily be rewritten without it.

With this version you can do both

```
auto v = make_unique<std::vector<int>>(10, 20); // *v is a vector of 10 elements
```

and

```
auto p = make_unique<point>(10, 20); // *p is a point (10, 20)
```